# VS 2015 integration with Gulp JS unit tests

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, gulp

I am using Gulp + Karma to run my Jasmine Javascript tests under PhantomJS (headless browser).

This works fine and the output of each test is sent to the Task Runner Explorer window. I want to be able to report those tests within VS though. Specifically I want to do so within an automated build environment such that if they fail during the automated build process I want to be notified as it would be if a standard C# unit test failed.

How can I get this working?

Here is my current test task

```
gulp.task('test', function (coverage) {
    gulp.src(allFiles)
    .pipe(karma({
        configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
        action: 'run'
    }))
    .on('error', function (err) {
        // Make sure failed tests cause gulp to exit non-zero
        console.log("error: tests failed");
        throw err;
    });
});
```

Comment: There is a support in Visual Studio for Gulp and so http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingGulpGruntBowerAndNpmSupportForVisualStudio.aspx

I didn't do that from while but the last time I used chutzpah to run my Jasmine tests in VS https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/71a4e9bd-f660-448f-bd92-f5a65d39b7f0 (I saw that there is also gulp-chutzpah)

Answer (score 0):

I also have similar kind of requirement. I have implemented one solution which fails MSBuild whenever any Unit Test failed. But as you mentioned you want to be notified as it would be if a standard C# unit test failed. As per my implementation that is not possible yet.

If failing the MSBuild on unit tests failing is fine with you, you can refer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38893725/5396181